# Error: Expected unqualified-id before numeric constant with Eigen3 Library and PCL

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, eigen3

I'm working with Point Cloud Library. This library uses Eigen3 library for some methods. I try to compile my project but there is some compilation errors that I do not able to solve. The error is:

```
Error: Expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
```

I already searched a solution here, but my conditions are different. The error stack is:

```
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/IterativeLinearSolvers:34:0,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Sparse:24,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/features/eigen.h:49,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/features/principal_curvatures.h:44,
                 from /home/PROJECTS/Pipeline/include/mypcl.h:31,
                 from /home/PROJECTS/Pipeline/include/elementset.h:24,
                 from /home/PROJECTS/Pipeline/data.h:24,
                 from /home/PROJECTS/Pipeline/inputhandler.h:16,
                 from /home/PROJECTS/Pipeline/inputhandler.cpp:1:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/IterativeLinearSolvers/ConjugateGradient.h: In function ‘void Eigen::internal::conjugate_gradient(const MatrixType&, const Rhs&, Dest&, const Preconditioner&, int&, typename Dest::RealScalar&)’:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/IterativeLinearSolvers/ConjugateGradient.h:38:14: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
```

The problematic code follows:

```
  using std::sqrt;
  using std::abs;
  typedef typename Dest::RealScalar RealScalar;
  typedef typename Dest::Scalar Scalar;
  typedef Matrix<Scalar,Dynamic,1> VectorType;

  RealScalar tol = tol_error;  <-- ERROR
  int maxIters = iters;

  int n = mat.cols();

  VectorType residual = rhs - mat * x; //initial residual
```

The most problematic thing is this code is not mine, and few weeks ago it run. Few days ago I done some automatic updates, but I don't know if is related to this error.

Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It sounds like one of the names (probably `tol`) is conflicting with a macro with the same name. Find the macro, and terminate it with extreme prejudice.

Comment: Ok, perfect! It's solved. Thank you very much. However, I don't understand why it was working before. I didn't change anything and this my "tol" was already there for a long time. Anyway... Thanks again. :D